# Geoip with MySQL

Tags: mysql, geoip

I have a MySQL database that contains the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `session` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `success` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `session` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `starttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endtime` datetime default NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `geoip_blocks` (
  `gbl_block_start` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `gbl_block_end` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `gbl_glc_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gbl_block_start`,`gbl_block_end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `geoip_locations` (
  `glc_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `glc_country` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `glc_region` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `glc_city` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `glc_zip` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `glc_latitude` decimal(7,4) NOT NULL,
  `glc_longitude` decimal(7,4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`glc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

where `geoip_blocks` and `geoip_locations` are imported from MaxMind's free legacy geolocation database.

I want to create a report with timestamps, IP numbers and geolocation data (country, latitude, longitude) of all sessions for which `auth.success` is equal to 1.

I can easily create a report of timestamps and IP numbers of all sessions for which `auth.success` is equal to 1:

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(auth.timestamp) as time_sec,
  sessions.ip as ip
FROM auth
  INNER JOIN sessions ON auth.session = sessions.session
WHERE auth.success = 1
```

Given a single IP number `ip`, I can get geolocation data for it:

```
SELECT
  geoip_locations.glc_country as country,
  geoip_locations.glc_latitude as lat,
  geoip_locations.glc_longitude as lon
FROM geoip_blocks INNER JOIN geoip_locations
  ON geoip_locations.glc_id = geoip_blocks.gbl_glc_id
WHERE gbl_block_start <= INET_ATON(ip)
ORDER BY gbl_block_start DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But what kind of query should I use to obtain the kind of report I need (for all the IPs that the first query above would produce)?

Answer (score 0):

The following query worked when I tested it with a few entries in your tables.
I created the tables in database named `soq`.
I found one syntax error in your create statements. Your `sessions` table primary key should be `session` instead of `id`. I'll try to edit your question to fix that.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(auth.timestamp) as time_sec,
  auth.timestamp,
  sessions.ip as ip,
  geoip_locations.glc_country as country,
  geoip_locations.glc_latitude as lat,
  geoip_locations.glc_longitude as lon
FROM soq.geoip_blocks JOIN soq.geoip_locations ON (geoip_locations.glc_id = geoip_blocks.gbl_glc_id)
  LEFT JOIN (soq.auth JOIN soq.sessions ON auth.session = sessions.session) -- nested join
  ON (gbl_block_start <= INET_ATON(ip) AND gbl_block_end >= INET_ATON(ip))
  WHERE success = 1
ORDER BY gbl_block_start DESC;
```

Here is example query result:

```
# time_sec, timestamp, ip, country, lat, lon
'1502385000', '2017-08-10 13:10:00', '5.82.243.128', 'SA', '25.0000', '45.0000'
'1502401200', '2017-08-10 17:40:00', '1.40.42.8', 'AU', '-27.0000', '133.0000'
'1502393400', '2017-08-10 15:30:00', '1.40.42.255', 'AU', '-27.0000', '133.0000'
```

Here is some test data that I used:

```
-- AU loc_id = 17   19409408 = 1.40.42.0        19409663 = 1.40.42.255
-- SA loc_id - 186  89322240 = 5.82.243.0       89325567 = 5.82.255.255
INSERT INTO soq.sessions (`session`, `starttime`, `endtime`, `ip`) VALUES('userSession1',NOW(), ADDTIME(NOW(),'01:02:00'),'1.40.42.255');
INSERT INTO soq.sessions (`session`, `starttime`, `endtime`, `ip`) VALUES('userSession2',ADDTIME(NOW(),'02:03:00'), ADDTIME(NOW(),'03:04:00'),'1.40.42.8');
INSERT INTO soq.sessions (`session`, `starttime`, `endtime`, `ip`) VALUES('userSession3','2017-08-10 13:00:00', '2017-08-10 16:37:00','5.82.243.128');

INSERT INTO soq.auth (`session`, `success`, `username`, `password`, `timestamp`) VALUES('userSession1',1,'user1','pwd1','2017-08-10 15:30:00');
INSERT INTO soq.auth (`session`, `success`, `username`, `password`, `timestamp`) VALUES('userSession2',1,'user2','pwd2','2017-08-10 17:40:00');
INSERT INTO soq.auth (`session`, `success`, `username`, `password`, `timestamp`) VALUES('userSession3',1,'user3','pwd3','2017-08-10 13:10:00');
INSERT INTO soq.auth (`session`, `success`, `username`, `password`, `timestamp`) VALUES('userSession3',0,'user3','pwd3','2017-08-10 13:00:00');

-- 19409408 19409663    17
-- 89322240 89325567    186
INSERT INTO soq.geoip_blocks VALUES(19409408,19409663,17);
INSERT INTO soq.geoip_blocks VALUES(89322240,89325567,186);

-- 17   AU              -27 133
-- 186  SA              25  45
INSERT INTO soq.geoip_locations VALUES (17,'AU','','','',-27,133);
INSERT INTO soq.geoip_locations VALUES (186,'SA','','','',25,45);
```

Comment: This query seems horrendously inefficient. I don't even know if it works at all - I had to abort it after it spent half an hour without producing any results.

I've found a different solution of my problem, using a nested `SELECT`, but that too is way too inefficient - takes about a minute and a half to process 24 hours worth of data.

I'll have to re-arrange the table structures and come up with something else.